# It gives error when I put button in Carousel

Tags: actions-on-google

It gives error and throws me out of app. I want to go youtube link when i push a selected item.
When i delete buttons it works but it doesn't go link url.
error is MalformedResponse Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of invalid platform response: Could not find a RichResponse or SystemIntent in the platform response

```
    conv.ask(new Carousel({
        items: {
            'item 1': {
                title: 'item 1',
                buttons: new Button({
                    title: 'This is a button',
                    url: 'https://www.youtube.com/',
                }),
                url: 'https://www.youtube.com/',
                description: 'Description of item 1',
                image: new Image({
                    url: 'https://www.youtube.com/',
                    alt: 'aa',
                })
            },

            'item 2': {
                title: 'item 2',
                buttons: new Button({
                    title: 'This is a button 2',
                    url: 'https://www.youtube.com/',
                }),
                url: 'https://www.youtube.com',
                description: 'Descript',
                image: new Image({
                    url: 'https://www.youtube.com/',
                    alt: 'item 2',
                })
            },
        },
    }));
```

Comment: Could you update your question and include the error that you are getting?

Comment: MalformedResponse Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of invalid platform response: Could not find a RichResponse or SystemIntent in the platform response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a set of items with links, you will want to use a [BrowseCarousel](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/responses#browsing_carousel) instead of a regular carousel. Keep in mind that a BrowseCarousel doesn't have buttons.

```
conv.ask(new BrowseCarousel({
    items: [
      new BrowseCarouselItem({
        title: 'Title of item 1',
        url: 'https://example.com',
        description: 'Description of item 1',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Image alternate text',
        }),
        footer: 'Item 1 footer',
      }),
      new BrowseCarouselItem({
        title: 'Title of item 2',
        url: 'https://example.com',
        description: 'Description of item 2',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Image alternate text',
        }),
        footer: 'Item 2 footer',
      }),
    ],
  }));
```